# OSX Photos, Applescript: loop through Moments?

Tags: applescript, osx-elcapitan, photos

I am very new to AppleScript but have worked extensively (for years) with other scripting languages, so not entirely new to the game.  I have just sadly said goodbye to Aperture and imported my nearly 100K digital images into Photos (so I'm also brand new to Photos).  I would like to make a sane structure for finding images, i.e.

```
Folders named for Year (e.g. 2004)
contain Folders named for Month (e.g. 05)
contain Albums named for each day for which there are images (e.g. 2004-05-03)
(yes this is basically the Picasa convention, which I am accustomed to and like)
```

Having imported my 100K images into Photos, apparently with success, I find that they are organised by default into "Moments"  (i.e. dates), but there is no hierarchical organisation to make browsing easier, as above.  So I would like to write an AppleScript to do as follows:

```
foreach Moment
   parse the date and create folder for year if it does not exist already
   create folder inside year for month if not exists already
   create album inside month for day, if not exists already
   assign all photos in this Moment to that album
```

Seems simple enough, and it would take tens of hours by hand :-) so never going to happen unless I can script it.  I've been reading the (seemingly rather limited) AppleScript dictionary for Photos and so far have not seen any useful reference to Moments, as in how to loop through a list of them all, find list of images contained in one, etc.  I see the object "moment" defined with two attributes, ID and name;  but I'm floundering around a bit trying to find the master list of all Moments or the contents of Moments.

I have a feeling that 2 paragraphs or one chunk of sample code from someone familiar with this app (and with AppleScript) would save me hours of googling.  Does anyone know how to go about this?

[update]

I have tried DLing and installing a promising script library for Photos

https://photosautomation.com/scripting/script-library.html

but so far have not been able to get any of its functions to execute.  I have also tried the most basic exploratory command to Photos:

```
tell application "Photos"
    activate
    set moms to the moments of application
    display dialog moms
end tell
```

and got a not-too-enlightening error message:

```
error "Can’t get every moment of application." number -1728 from every «class IPmm» of application
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this on Yosemite (10.10.5) for Photos 1.0.1 so it may need some modifications for you, but it's the best I could do, hopefully it will work on your OS. I tried to comment it for you so you'd be able to see what it was doing.

```
on run
    tell application "Photos"
        set mediaItems to every media item
        repeat with mediaItem in mediaItems
            set mdate to (date of mediaItem) -- get the date of the file
            set yearName to year of mdate as string -- year of the file
            set YrFolder to my yearFolder(yearName) -- make the year folder

            set mmonth to month of mdate -- month of the file
            set monthName to my monthNum(mmonth as string) -- month name as a number
            set SubFold to my subFolder(monthName, YrFolder) -- make the month number folder

            set mday to day of mdate -- day of the file
            set dayName to my dayNum(mday as string) -- get the day as a two digit number
            set albumName to yearName & "-" & monthName & "-" & dayName as string -- create the album name
            set finalAlbum to my makeAlbum(albumName, SubFold) -- make the album

            add {mediaItem} to finalAlbum -- put the item in the album
        end repeat
    end tell

end run


on dayNum(mday)
    if (count of characters in mday) = 1 then
        return "0" & mday as string
    else
        return mday as string
    end if
end dayNum

on monthNum(mmonth)
    if mmonth = "January" then
        set num to "01"
    else if mmonth = "February" then
        set num to "02"
    else if mmonth = "March" then
        set num to "03"
    else if mmonth = "April" then
        set num to "04"
    else if mmonth = "May" then
        set num to "05"
    else if mmonth = "June" then
        set num to "06"
    else if mmonth = "July" then
        set num to "07"
    else if mmonth = "August" then
        set num to "08"
    else if mmonth = "September" then
        set num to "09"
    else if mmonth = "October" then
        set num to "10"
    else if mmonth = "November" then
        set num to "11"
    else if mmonth = "December" then
        set num to "12"
    end if
    return num
end monthNum


on makeAlbum(albName, theFolder)
    tell application "Photos"
        set yrFold to name of parent of theFolder
        if exists container albName of container (name of theFolder) of container yrFold then
            return (container albName of container (name of theFolder) of container yrFold)
        else
            return make new album named albName at theFolder
        end if
    end tell
end makeAlbum


on subFolder(subName, YrFolder)
    tell application "Photos"
        if exists container subName of container (name of YrFolder) then
            return container subName of container (name of YrFolder)
        else
            return make new folder named subName at YrFolder
        end if
    end tell
end subFolder

on yearFolder(yearName)
    tell application "Photos"
        if container named yearName exists then
            return container named yearName
        else
            try
                return make new folder named yearName
            on error
                return ""
            end try
        end if
    end tell
end yearFolder
```

Best of luck with it, would love to know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks TBD.  AS syntax is fairly readable so I get the gist.  One thing that confuses me slightly is the number of return statements, as in the subFolder proc where you tell Photos blah blah, if x then return A, else return B.  Then comes end tell, but then there's another return (return NewFold) and NewFold has never been declared anywhere.

in yearFolder however there is no final return outside the tell block.  so I'm a bit puzzled by that.  off to google AS return syntax.  many thanks for the sample code -- one example is worth 1K man pages :-)

Comment: @DeClarke you're correct, that makes no sense. Lol. That was an error on my part, but it will never hit that last return as the other two will always catch everything. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: This script is amazing. Just run it on my 1500+ photos and everything is nicely grouped now in Albums. What sucks is that "Export" doesn't respect albums hierarchy as far as I can tell. E.g.: can't really export all these Albums to directory hierarchy YYYY/MM/YYYY-MM-DD/photo01.JPG etc..

Comment: This script is excellent, @ThrowBackDewd need save image url to photos application, can you have any save image script code?

Answer (score 1):

[Current working version](http://pastebin.com/uJqVJi3n)

Code is now too long to post here, but thanks for the starting point!  it's running even now -- painfully slowly, of course, but seems to be working.  There are over 97K images in my Photos library so this could take days.  [update:  10000 images every 2 hours, so about 18 hours] AS syntax still strikes me as decidedly odd :-) but thanks to your sample code I could whack this together PDQ and, I hope, solve the problem.

[update]  YES, it worked.  about 20 hrs run time, zero errors, and looks like success.  thanks very much for the code sample.  problem solved.

Comment: Great script! But it doesn't really 'loop through moments' as title indicates. If I export from Photos using 'moment name' for subfolder, then I get directories like this: 

`Rome - Castro Pretorio - Via Vittorio Emanuele Orlando, August 13, 2015`  - Full address and date, unfriendly format.

Your script creates folders for the year, and then each month in the year. I'd love if it would include the address (part of the 'moment') as well, so that it could use that in the subfolder names.

'Moments' are accessible, but how?

`Moment: contains media items; contained by application.`