# How do I change this script to only run for specific months or years, rather than review my whole Photos library?

Tags: macos, applescript, photos, macos-high-sierra

I came across this script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611477/osx-photos-applescript-loop-through-moments)

```
on run
    tell application "Photos"
        set mediaItems to every media item
        repeat with mediaItem in mediaItems
            set mdate to (date of mediaItem) -- get the date of the file
            set yearName to year of mdate as string -- year of the file
            set YrFolder to my yearFolder(yearName) -- make the year folder

            set mmonth to month of mdate -- month of the file
            set monthName to my monthNum(mmonth as string) -- month name as a number
            set SubFold to my subFolder(monthName, YrFolder) -- make the month number folder

            set mday to day of mdate -- day of the file
            set dayName to my dayNum(mday as string) -- get the day as a two digit number
            set albumName to yearName & "-" & monthName & "-" & dayName as string -- create the album name
            set finalAlbum to my makeAlbum(albumName, SubFold) -- make the album

            add {mediaItem} to finalAlbum -- put the item in the album
        end repeat
    end tell

end run


on dayNum(mday)
    if (count of characters in mday) = 1 then
        return "0" & mday as string
    else
        return mday as string
    end if
end dayNum

on monthNum(mmonth)
    if mmonth = "January" then
        set num to "01"
    else if mmonth = "February" then
        set num to "02"
    else if mmonth = "March" then
        set num to "03"
    else if mmonth = "April" then
        set num to "04"
    else if mmonth = "May" then
        set num to "05"
    else if mmonth = "June" then
        set num to "06"
    else if mmonth = "July" then
        set num to "07"
    else if mmonth = "August" then
        set num to "08"
    else if mmonth = "September" then
        set num to "09"
    else if mmonth = "October" then
        set num to "10"
    else if mmonth = "November" then
        set num to "11"
    else if mmonth = "December" then
        set num to "12"
    end if
    return num
end monthNum


on makeAlbum(albName, theFolder)
    tell application "Photos"
        set yrFold to name of parent of theFolder
        if exists container albName of container (name of theFolder) of container yrFold then
            return (container albName of container (name of theFolder) of container yrFold)
        else
            return make new album named albName at theFolder
        end if
    end tell
end makeAlbum


on subFolder(subName, YrFolder)
    tell application "Photos"
        if exists container subName of container (name of YrFolder) then
            return container subName of container (name of YrFolder)
        else
            return make new folder named subName at YrFolder
        end if
    end tell
end subFolder

on yearFolder(yearName)
    tell application "Photos"
        if container named yearName exists then
            return container named yearName
        else
            try
                return make new folder named yearName
            on error
                return ""
            end try
        end if
    end tell
end yearFolder
```

I've tried running it, and the principal of what it's doing works fine.  Eventually I get an error "Photos got a error: AppleEvent timed out."

My photos library is over 54k images, so going through every image means this process takes a very long time.

I don't actually need to do this for every single photo, but would like to do it for just a specific year or month.

Is there anything I can tweak in the script to make this more specific than applying to my whole library.  I'm brand new to AppleScript, so have no idea how I'd go about this.

Many thanks